# ordered comparison between pointer and integer objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I've searched for this and actually found alot of results, but I am such a beginner at this that I've got a problem using their answers on my specific case.

My code:

```
  + (NSUInteger)maxRank { return [self rankStrings].count - 1; }

  - (void)setRank:(NSUInteger )rank {
      if(rank <= [PlayingCard maxRank]) {
          _rank = rank;
      }
  }
```

"self rankStrings" is just an array containing a number of strings.

The if statement is, of course, the line that gives the error. I am just unable to understand how the error occurs, I am actually following a lesson from a man called Paul from Stanford and this is his code *exactly* with the only difference being his working and mine not so much.

As i understand it, maxRank returns a NSUInteger (not a pointer) and in the setter for "rank", "rank" isn't a pointer either. I just dont get it. The rank property looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;
```

Hopefully someone can come up with an answer, got my self a headache because of this.

Comment: What is the precise error? Copy-paste it.

Comment: Have you explicitly declared the instance variable? Did you explicitly `@synthesize` the property or did you let the compiler do so implicitly?

Comment: "ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') and 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *'))

Comment: I did not synthesize it since i only added the setter and not the getter

Comment: The code snippet in your question has a suspicious space in the argument type. There's no problem from a syntax point of view, but I wonder if your real code has an asterisk there that you've omitted from the question.

Comment: @user2057182 Is `rank` declared as a pointer to NSUInteger in the `setRank`method?

Comment: @KenThomases I've copy pasted the code, there is no asterisk there. edit; i removed the space i guess you were talking about, between "NSUInteger" and ")".

Comment: @DanielMartín I dont really understand? Sorry, as i said, not really fluent with this..

Comment: You searched [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.hu/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)?

Comment: Is this the only warning? Does the declaration of `+maxRank` in the `@interface` match the definition of that method you posted above?

Comment: Also, this has asbolutely **nothing** to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Comment: Well this was embarrassing, now that you mentioned it the +maxRank actually had a asterisk in its declaration. That solved the warning at least, sorry for taking your time with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property maxRank was declared as a pointer in the .h file. Removing the * in the property declaration fixed it.

Comment: another noob mistake (of mine): establishing values in the header (.h) file.  initializing variables in the viewDidLoad solved "DUPLICATE SYMBOL" error.  UPVOTED! :)